# Changing specific wpf datagrid row color using c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a requirement to change color of specific data grid row at run time

I am setting row background color inside Loading Row event of data grid

```
 private void MessagesDataGrid_LoadingRow(objects , DataGridRowEventArgs e)
   {           
      var v = e.Row.Item.ToString();
      int i = e.Row.GetIndex();
      if (IoStatusViewModel.HighlightSelected == true  )
      {
         e.Row.Focusable = true;
         e.Row.Background = Brushes.Red;
         if (v.Contains("MCP :"))
         {
             DisplayLogs = IoStatusViewModel.ChangeMcpLog(v);
             e.Row.Item = DisplayLogs;
         }
      }          
     else
     {
        if (v.Contains("MCP :"))
        {
         DisplayLogs = IoStatusViewModel.ChangeMcpLog(v);
         e.Row.Item = DisplayLogs;
        }
      }                                       
    }
```

This code is working fine as data grid loads but after some times the color of each rows in data grid starts changing and as time passes whole grid becomes red

Comment: Did you try making a field in this class (for example int _lastIndex), and in the MessagesDataGrid_LoadingRow, before setting the new row background color to red, first set the previous row index (_lastIndex) background color to white, or whatever it was before you made it red?

Comment: DataGridLoadingRow event will be called once when you loaded the items in DataGrid. Changes DataGrid Row background color based on the content of DataGrid cell (based on the property of your collection) like 

**Code**    
 var ds = e.Row.Item as TestEnableButton;            
 if(ds.IsEnableButton)                
   e.Row.Background = Brushes.Red;

Answer (score 2):

I would do it within the class object you are binding against in conjunction with a style for the grid.  First, your data being presented in the grid.  How/where is that coming from.  Is it some sort of List<> or ObservableCollect<> of items.  Example

```
var yourBoundProperty = new List<SomeClass>();
```

… populate however you do.

```
public class SomeClass
{
   public string SomeProp {get; set;}
   public string YourMCPField {get; set;}
   // make a SPECIAL FIELD... could be boolean, number setting, whatever flag
   // but in this case, I just have boolean
   public bool FieldContainsMCP { get { return YourMCPFieldContains( "MCP :"); }}
}
```

Now, in your Xaml… assuming in a Window declaration.

```
<Window … >
   <Window.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" x:Key="MyColorTriggers">
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FieldContainsMCP}" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
               <Setter Property="ExampleAnyOtherProperty" Value="someOtherValue" />
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </Window.Resources>


   <DataGrid  … other settings you have
      CellStyle="{StaticResource MyColorTriggers}" >

      .. rest of your data column declarations

   </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

This way the actual data source is the flag basis which is applied to the CellStyle triggering regardless of where you may be scrolling through records.